# Why does the ngrams() function give distinct bigrams?

Tags: r, nlp, n-gram

I am writing an [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) script and am using library(ngram).

Suppose I have a string,

"good qualiti **dog food** bought sever vital can **dog food** product found good qualiti product look like stew process meat smell better labrador finicki appreci product better"

and want to find bi-grams.

The ngram library is giving me bi-grams as follows:

"appreci product" "process meat" "food product" "food bought" "qualiti dog" "product found" "product look" "look like" "like stew" "good qualiti" "labrador finicki" "bought sever" "qualiti product" "better labrador"
**"dog food"** "smell better" "vital can" "meat smell" "found good" "sever vital" "stew process" "can dog" "finicki appreci" "product better"

As the sentence contains "dog food" two times, I want this bi-gram two times. But I am getting it once!

Is there an option in thengram library or any other library that gives all the bi-grams of my sentence in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stylo` package. Gives duplicates:

```
library(stylo)
a = "good qualiti dog food bought sever vital can dog food product found good qualiti product look like stew process meat smell better labrador finicki appreci product better"
b = txt.to.words(a)
c = make.ngrams(b, ngram.size = 2)
print(c)
```

Result:

```
 [1] "good qualiti"     "qualiti dog"      "dog food"         "food bought"      "bought sever"     "sever vital"      "vital can"        "can dog"          "dog food"        
[10] "food product"     "product found"    "found good"       "good qualiti"     "qualiti product"  "product look"     "look like"        "like stew"        "stew process"    
[19] "process meat"     "meat smell"       "smell better"     "better labrador"  "labrador finicki" "finicki appreci"  "appreci product"  "product better"  
>
```

Answer (score 6):

The development version of [`ngram`](https://github.com/wrathematics/ngram) has a `get.phrasetable` method:

```
devtools::install_github("wrathematics/ngram")
library(ngram)

text <- "good qualiti dog food bought sever vital can dog food product found good qualiti product look like stew process meat smell better labrador finicki appreci product better"

ng <- ngram(text)
head(get.phrasetable(ng))
#            ngrams freq       prop
# 1    good qualiti    2 0.07692308
# 2        dog food    2 0.07692308
# 3 appreci product    1 0.03846154
# 4    process meat    1 0.03846154
# 5    food product    1 0.03846154
# 6     food bought    1 0.03846154
```

In addition, you can use the `print()` method and specify `output == "full"`. That is:

```
print(ng, output = "full")

# NOTE: more output not shown...
better labrador | 1 
finicki {1} | 

dog food | 2 
product {1} | bought {1} 
# NOTE: more output not shown...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use RWeka. In the result you can see "dog food" and "good qualiti" appearing twice

```
txt <- "good qualiti dog food bought sever vital can dog food product found good qualiti product look like stew process meat smell better labrador finicki appreci product better"


library(RWeka)
RWEKABigramTokenizer <- function(x) {
      NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2)) 
}

RWEKABigramTokenizer(txt)

 [1] "good qualiti"     "qualiti dog"      "dog food"         "food bought"      "bought sever"     "sever vital"      "vital can"       
 [8] "can dog"          "dog food"         "food product"     "product found"    "found good"       "good qualiti"     "qualiti product" 
[15] "product look"     "look like"        "like stew"        "stew process"     "process meat"     "meat smell"       "smell better"    
[22] "better labrador"  "labrador finicki" "finicki appreci"  "appreci product"  "product better"
```

Or use the tm package in combination with RWeka

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
my_corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
tdm_RWEKA <- TermDocumentMatrix(my_corp, control=list(tokenize = RWEKABigramTokenizer))

#show the 2 bigrams
findFreqTerms(tdm_RWEKA, lowfreq = 2)

[1] "dog food"     "good qualiti"

#turn into matrix with frequency counts
tdm_matrix <- as.matrix(tdm_RWEKA)
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to produce such bi-gram, you don't need any special package. Basically, split the text and paste it together again.

```
t <- "good qualiti dog food bought sever vital can dog food product found good qualiti product look like stew process meat smell better labrador finicki appreci product better"
ug <- strsplit(t, " ")[[1]]
bg <- paste(ug, ug[2:length(ug)])
```

The resulted `bg` would be:

```
[1] "good qualiti"     "qualiti dog"      "dog food"
[4] "food bought"      "bought sever"     "sever vital"
[7] "vital can"        "can dog"          "dog food"
[10] "food product"     "product found"    "found good"
[13] "good qualiti"     "qualiti product"  "product look"
[16] "look like"        "like stew"        "stew process"
[19] "process meat"     "meat smell"       "smell better"
[22] "better labrador"  "labrador finicki" "finicki appreci"
[25] "appreci product"  "product better"   "better qualiti"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the **quanteda** package:

```
> quanteda::tokenize(txt, ngrams = 2, concatenator = " ")
[[1]]
 [1] "good qualiti"     "qualiti dog"      "dog food"         "food bought"      "bought sever"     "sever vital"     
 [7] "vital can"        "can dog"          "dog food"         "food product"     "product found"    "found good"      
[13] "good qualiti"     "qualiti product"  "product look"     "look like"        "like stew"        "stew process"    
[19] "process meat"     "meat smell"       "smell better"     "better labrador"  "labrador finicki" "finicki appreci" 
[25] "appreci product"  "product better"
```

Plenty of additional arguments available through `ngrams`, including getting different combinations of n sizes, or skip-grams.